# Value. Error when doing a string strip and attempting to convert object column to an integer in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am attempting to strip out any characters other than numbers in a column and then convert that column from an object to integer, but I am receiving an error message.

```
data.dtypes

Column1          object
```

the column of interest has numbers but also `','` in it which I believe is preventing it from turning into an integer. What I tried was this but got the subsequent error message

```
data['Column1'] = data['Column1'].str.strip(',').astype(int)

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '21,690'
```

I can edit and post the entire error message is that is helpful. But I'm assuming that having the ',' in the column is causing the issue. I don't believe there are any other characters in the column, but not sure.

Ultimately I'd like that column just transformed to int data type and stripped of any non numeric values.

*edit*

I also checked for null values with

```
data.isnull().sum() * 100 / len(data)

Column1   0.00000
```

however trying this results in the following error message

```
data['Column1'] = data['Column1'].str.replace(",", "").astype(int)

ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

Not entirely sure why.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
data['Column1'] = data['Column1'].str.replace(",", "").astype(int)
```

Comment: Ok, when I do that, I get `ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer`, however when I check the column with `data.isnull().sum() * 100 / len(data)` column1 is `column1     0.00000`.  which indicates it has no null values

Comment: @JLuu `NaN` is not necessarily the same as null.  Put a try/except around that line of code and print the offending value.

Comment: heh, I apologize, what exactly am I doing and putting try/except around?

Answer (score 0):

`strip` removes only leading and trailing characters. For internal characters, you can use regex, but it's simpler to do `replace(',' , '')`.

Also, as far as debugging, you can do something along these lines:

```
conversion_none_type_count = 0
conversion_non_int_count = 0
conversion_other_error = 0
conversion_none_types = []
conversion_other_errors = []

def try_convert(cell):
    global conversion_none_type_count
    global conversion_non_int_count
    global conversion_other_error
    global conversion_other_errors 
    global conversion_none_types 
    if not cell:
        conversion_null_count += 1
        conversion_none_types.append(cell)
        return 0
    try:
        cell_as_float = float(cell)
    except Exception as exception:
        conversion_other_error += 1
        conversion_other_errors.append(type(exception).__name__)
        return 0
    if cell_as_float % 1:
         conversion_non_int_count += 1
    return int(cell_as_float)

data['conversion_attempt'] = data['Column1'].apply(try_convert(cell))
```

You'll now have `conversion_null_count`, `conversion_non_int_count`, and `conversion_other_error` as the count of number of nulls, floats that aren't integers, and other errors, respectively, while `conversion_none_types` will be a list of all the none-types in the column, and `conversion_other_errors` will be a list of the other errors.